# What is the precise meaning of "M est lié à N"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

> Microsoft est **lié à** votre entreprise.

Does "M est lié à N" mean in a neutral sense that M and N has some kind of relation, or does it have a stronger meaning that their relation is a friendly one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means there is some sort of link between both companies but only the context could explain what kind of link it is, technical, business, historical or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

So, depending on the context, this can have several meanings, but in general, it means that there is some kind of relation between both companies.

---

For instance, if the context is about both firms doing business together:

> « Microsoft est **lié** à votre entreprise. »

would mean that you have economic relations

---

If the context is about some relative relation, then

> « Microsoft est **lié** à votre entreprise. »

would mean that there is a physical relation

Comment: It seems quite bizarre to talk about a "physical relation" between corporate entities...